# searchSite - responds with a File not found

Tags: yodlee

I'm using the postman extension for chrome and trying to work with the yodlee.com 'searchSite' endpoint. I enter the cobSessionToken and the userSessionToken however I'm not too sure about what to enter in the 'siteSearchString' parameter. It seems like whatever I enter just returns with a

```
File Not Found 
The requested web page was not found on this server. Please use the back button and try again.
```

Is it usual with the sample test case that you provide with the account to have such error? Every other step seems to be working fine except for this "searchSite."

Answer (score 0):

The 'siteSearchString' is what bank you want to search for. An example search string that should work is 'wells' which should return several results for Wells Fargo.

Instead of using postman, I would recommend using  https://developer.yodlee.com/TestDrive which will let you fill in the parameters, provide suggested values for the parameters, and view the json results of the REST request.